# Make dynamic align if overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a table with table headers. I'm using a fixed 35px width for the individual columns. So, for that purpose I have used table-layout:fixed and overflow:hidden so that the individual cells fit in the assigned width and not expand dynamically. But, the table headers are center aligned. So, the overflow:hidden makes it cut from both sides. Eg if the table header is ABCDEFGH, then the header displayed is CDEF.

I need to have the center alignment for headers and would not like to lose the left side of the header text as well . Any way this is possible? I use Java btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to assign the "overflow:hidden" to the data cells only. Something like:

```
.my-table-class th
{
  /* styles here */
}

.my-table-class td
{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I want for my headers itself to behave with overflow:hidden. But as they are center aligned (and I intend to have them that way), these header text gets truncated from both the sides and I will be having only the middle part of the headers. Some headers will fit in the cell (with center aligned) but some other headers will get truncated. So for those some other cells I want them to dynamically be assigned align:left.

Comment: Ah, would it be possible to put a container around the header text, center the container inside of the header, and then apply the alignment and overflow styles to container itself?